# Cordova can't create app package for windows Store

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-store

I'm creating an app with cordova and I need to release it on the windows store (is already in the App store and in the process to be released on the play store so the app itself is working) so I've cloned my cordova app on a windows machine downloaded the Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 community edition and created a new project from existing code selecting apache cordova in the wizard.

And I can run the app on emulator and a real device but when I try to "Project" -> "Store" -> "Create App Packages..." I always fail the verification but the strange thing is that it looks that all the test are passed but at the end I got an error suggesting to check in the folder: "C:\Users[$user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\AppCertKit" for the log but the AppcertKit folder dosen't even exist and even if I create a new one is always empty.

If I try to upload the .appxupload file created in  "\platforms\windows\AppPackages" I get always two errors about:
Invalid package family name 
Invalid package publisher name: CN=Apache Cordova Team (expected

even if I select the remote app in the wizard for the creation of the packages.

I'm using:
Visual Studio 2017 15.2
Cordova (6.3.1 / 6.5 / 7.0.1) I've tried all of them.
Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Same thing is happening to me.  I associate the project in Visual studio / Store with the existing app.  But it always gets the last part of the family name wrong and for the publisher name it gets Apache Cordova Team.

Answer (score 2):

> If I try to upload the .appxupload file created in
>   "\platforms\windows\AppPackages" I get always two errors about:
>   Invalid package family name Invalid package publisher name: CN=Apache
>   Cordova Team (expected even if I select the remote app in the wizard
>   for the creation of the packages.

According to the submission error, the identity info of your package cannot be recognized by Dev Center.

To upload your package, you need to associate your project with the app name you reserved in Dev Center to match the identity info:
[image]

For more details, you can refer to [**Package your Windows version Cordova app**](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/#package-the-windows-version-of-your-app).

Comment: I do that but I get the same error. I tried to associate the app and then create the package and associate the package in the create package wizard but nothinf works